# Windows 10 Batch or powershell script for WLAN

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, powershell, batch-file, shell-script

Can someone help me to create a batch script to automatically connect to an ***SSID: SDWLAN*** and if already connected skip re-connection to avoid dropping the existing connection.

My intent is to setup a task to run every 3 minutes from 8 AM to 5 PM for a group of users.

At this time this is what I have but not working :( and any explanation or modification will be much appreciated. :)

```
netsh wlan show interface | find "SDWLAN"
IF EXIST "SDWLAN" GOTO end
netsh wlan connect name="SDWLAN"
:end
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your batch script like this way :

**Remark :** Code edited (adding comments in the batch script)

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Connect to WLAN
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Setting the SSID Name variable here
Set "SSID=SDWLAN"
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Testing the wlan is connected or no by piping it to findstr as a regular expression
@REM The following switches used here with findstr
@REM /I Case-insensitive search
@REM /R Evaluate as a regular expression.
@REM commandA && commandB || commandC
@REM If commandA succeeds run commandB, if commandA fails run commandC
@REM Note that if commandB fails, that will also trigger running commandC.
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
netsh wlan show interface | findstr /I /R "%SSID%">nul && (
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM if this is true we show that we are connecting
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Color 0A & echo You are connected to SSID:"%SSID%"
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Else We try we connect to the SSID
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ) || (
        netsh wlan connect name="%SSID%"
    )
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Timeout to wait 3 seconds to show the message and exit the batch script
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak>nul & Exit /B
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

further reading about used commands in this batch script :

- [Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Timeout /?](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

Comment: A few comments would be helpful to understand the code

Comment: @Albin I edited the code and added some comments !

Comment: Wow, this was super helpful! Thank you very much and the explanation is amazing. :)

Comment: @Hackoo very good, thanks for your efford!